# Fold operation in Scala Vs Java 8

Tags: scala, java-8, java-stream

How to perform the below Scala operation to find the most frequent character in a string in java 8?

```
val tst = "Scala is awesomestttttts"
val op  = tst.foldLeft(Map[Char,Int]())((a,b) => {
    a+(b -> ((a.getOrElse(b, 0))+1))
  }).maxBy(f => f._2)
```

Here the output is

```
(Char, Int) = (t,6)
```

I was able to get a stream of characters in Java 8 like this:

```
Stream<Character> sch = tst.chars().mapToObj(i -> (char)i);
```

but not able to figure out whats the fold/foldLeft/foldRight alternative we have in Java 8

Can someone pls help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this seems to match with the Scala code you provided (if I understand it correctly):

```
String tst = "Java is awesomestttttts";
Optional<Map.Entry<Character, Long>> max =
    tst.chars()
       .mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                                      Collectors.counting()))
       .entrySet()
       .stream()
       .max(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue));
System.out.println(max.orElse(null));
```

Comment: `System.out.println(Collections.max(tst.chars().boxed() .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i->(char)(int)i,Collectors.counting())).entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue()));`

Comment: @Holger That doesn't compile in intellij 15

Comment: @Federico Peralta Schaffner: when I copy it from my comment, it doesn’t work either, because somehow, a [`U+200C`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200c/index.htm)[`U+200B`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm) sequence got in between the `(` and `)` of the `emptySet()`, invisible but causing compiler errors. After removing these two illegal characters, it compiles fine with Netbeans and javac.

Comment: @Holger That was it, thanks. Maybe SO should remove invisible characters from comments? ;)

Comment: @Federico Peralta Schaffner: I don’t know whether it was me or SO adding it in the first place. I didn’t insert it intentionally. Sometimes, I feel like “adding a `U+00a0` could improve the formatting of my comment”, but then I immediately think “what if someone C&Ps my code example?” and refrain from it. On the other hand, `U+200C U+200B‌​` wouldn’t even improve the formatting and I’m not sure how to insert it with my keyboard…

Comment: @Holger Do you have a Mac? Some colleagues experienced similar issues with their Macs, though not here.

Comment: @Federico Peralta Schaffner: No, I have a NEO2 keyboard, allowing to enter a wide range of unicode characters, including special spacing, but it’s almost impossible to enter them accidentally, especially right between a `()` pair. It’s the first time, I experience it.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't mind using a third-party library [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) has a [`Bag`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/7.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/bag/Bag.html) type that can keep track of the character counts.  I've provided two examples below that use Bags.  Unfortunately there is no `maxByOccurrences` available today on `Bag`, but the same result can be achieved by using `topOccurrences(1)` which is available.  You can also use `forEachWithOccurrences` to find the max but it will be a little more code.

The following example uses a [`CharAdapter`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/7.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/string/immutable/CharAdapter.html), which is also included in Eclipse Collections.

```
MutableBag<Character> characters =
    CharAdapter.adapt("Scala is awesomestttttts")
        .collect(Character::toLowerCase)
        .toBag();
MutableList<ObjectIntPair<Character>> charIntPairs = characters.topOccurrences(2);

Assert.assertEquals(
    PrimitiveTuples.pair(Character.valueOf('t'), 6), charIntPairs.get(0));
Assert.assertEquals(
    PrimitiveTuples.pair(Character.valueOf('s'), 5), charIntPairs.get(1));
```

The second example uses the `chars()` method available on `String` which returns an `IntStream`.  It feels a bit awkward that something called chars() does not return a CharStream, but this is because `CharStream` is not available in JDK 8.

```
MutableBag<Character> characters =
    "Scala is awesomestttttts"
        .toLowerCase()
        .chars()
        .mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(Bags.mutable::empty));
MutableList<ObjectIntPair<Character>> charIntPairs = characters.topOccurrences(2);

Assert.assertEquals(
    PrimitiveTuples.pair(Character.valueOf('t'), 6), charIntPairs.get(0));
Assert.assertEquals(
    PrimitiveTuples.pair(Character.valueOf('s'), 5), charIntPairs.get(1));
```

In both examples, I converted the characters to lowercase first, so there are 5 occurrences of 's'.  If you want uppercase and lowercase letters to be distinct then just drop the lowercase code in both examples.

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample by the Stream in [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common):

```
String str = "Scala is awesomestttttts";
CharStream.from(str).boxed().groupBy(t -> t, Collectors.counting())
            .max(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue)).get();
```

But I think the simplest way by Multiset:

```
CharStream.from(str).toMultiset().maxOccurrences().get();
```